# Finding the number of solutions to cubic polynomial equations

Tags: factoring

I am looking to find the number of solutions to the following equation:
$$x^3 +0.1=10x$$

Looking at the graph of the expressions on each side of the equation I understand that there are 3 solutions.

How would I go about illustrating this point algebraically? My 1st instinct is to equate everything to 0
$$x^3 –10x + 0.1=0$$
but I would have no idea how to factorize this equation. Any tips?

Comment: The three roots aren't especially pleasant.    If you need values for them, you'll probably want to use numerical methods.  If all you want is to see that there are three roots, note that $p(-10)<0, p(0)>0,p(1)<0, p(10)>0$.

Comment: so without the use of a graphing calculator or attempting to graph the equation, is the only way to find the number of solutions is to test input values from various intervals that look pertinent?

Comment: I didn't say it was the only way.  But it's a good way.

Comment: yeah that's okay. I'm just looking for viable methods of tackling the problem algebraically without having to depend on visual graphs as some equations may be cumbersome to graph.

Comment: Well, evaluating the function at a few points is generally a good place to start.  Here you could also use calculus to find the local max and min, but I don't see that as any easier.  [Descartes' Rule of Signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) used to be a popular method but it has largely fallen out of favor as computational devices have become easy to use.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently working through Gelfands Functions and Graphs as a precalc prep so calculus is off-limits for now. I will review Descartes's rule of signs as you suggest but I only want to make sure I'm not missing any algebraic or mathematical techniques for solving such equations. Thanks for the input!

Comment: The beauty of simple evaluation is that applies to any function (well, at least any function which a computer can evaluate).  Of course, in general it just finds a lower bound on the number of roots.  if, say, you know that $f(0)>0$ and $f(1)>0$ you can't be sure that there isn't a root (or a hundred roots) between $0$ and $1$.  Polynomials are easier since you know there can't be more roots than the degree,

Comment: Indeed, looking at signs of output values at various input value intervals may cause presumptuous errors by missing multiple roots that may lie between those intervals. Also, I was unaware that the max number of roots of a polynomial is equal to its degree. Thinking about it, it makes sense. Thanks, I'm learning a lot!

Answer (score 0):

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Depressed_cubic.

A depressed cubic in general form is $t^3 + pt + q$. The discriminant $\Delta = -(4p^3 + 27q^2)$. The given equation $x^3 - 10x + 0.1 = 0$ has a depressed cubic on the LHS and $\Delta = 3999.73 > 0$.

If ${\Delta >0,}$ the cubic has **three distinct real roots**. (See *§Nature of the roots* in the linked Wikipedia article.)

Since we want just the number of roots, there is no need to even factor or calculate the actual roots.